Particle-vortex duality in 2+1 dimensions beyond the critical point
Is particle-vortex duality in 2+1 dimensions just a statement of the equality of the CFTs describing the phase transition of two different theories (XY and abelian-Higgs), or is the equivalence supposed to extend beyond the critical point?

IR dualities always extend to a small region around the critical point. This is because the small region can be explored by turning on deformations of the CFT, but the two theories flow to the same CFT, so they have the same space of deformations.

I believe the duality can hold more generally than only at the critical point.
For the bosonic particle-vortex duality, it is possible to map the partition function of the 3d classical XY model to that of a 3d lattice superconductor. This is carried out by Peskin in his paper titled Mandelstam-t'Hooft Duality in Abelian Lattice Models.
In this case, the particle-vortex duality is an exact statement even away from the critical point.
